# Dynamically create queries for google superproxy

Tags: dynamic, proxy, google-analytics-api

I am trying to implement google analytics for a website. Since I have to share data with users I don't want to authenticate them. I tried superproxy for this but issue is I want to write queries dynamically as I have to change the filters parameter value everytime.

I am unable to find any proper way to dynamically generate queries and send to superproxy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in GASuperProxy. But as of my understanding once we get the source of GASuperProxy, its our code from that point onwards and we are hosting it in app engine. Once its hosted it keeps a local copy of data which is periodically pulled from GA APIs.

Why can't you alter the code and have one API end point exposed to add the entries dynamically? I hope you are trying to add the dynamic queries from one of your admin apps which needs to authenticate to your GASuperProxy deployment.